# How to get the value from the ID

Tags: jquery

How to get the value of a radio buttons `ID` on click.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $('label').click(function() {           
            var total = 0;              
            $('.option:checked').each(function() {
                total += parseInt($(this).val());
            });             
            $('.sub-total-t').html('$' + total);                
        });
    });

</script>
```

This script works for `value` --> How do I assign the `ID` instead?

```
<label><input type="radio" name="print" class="option" id="25" value="p10"/> Starter 500 </label>
```

Comment: Do you want to get the ID of inputs?  `$('.option:checked').each(function() {
                alert(this.id)
             });`

Comment: Lol thanks all!! I see 4 ways to do the same thing. Very interesting.

Comment: How? `:)`. There are only 2 ways, `this.id`, `$(this).attr('id')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
$('.option:checked').each(function() {
    total += parseInt($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

But it's better to use the `data` attribute to store this kind of values:

```
<input data-number="25" />
```

And to retrieve it in javascript use this:

```
$(this).data('number')
```

For `number` you can use every name you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 total += parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
```

However, elements *should not* have a number as an id. The ID value should start with a letter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=radio]:checked').attr('id');
```

Try this..

In this case

```
    total += parseInt($(this).attr('id'));

OR 
  total += parseInt(this.id);  // This is faster
```

Comment: Just curious.. How can you say one is faster then the other?

Comment: In the later case we are using DOM object instead of jQuery Object.. So we are saving a step of not converting it to a jQuery object